# OnTouchListener for React Native

Tags: react-native

I'm looking for a method in React Native in which I can move an object by simply listening to the events KEY_DOWN, KEY_UP and KEY_MOVE. And as I move my finger on the component (KEY_MOVE), the position of the component moves along the X axis as per the new X axis I have. In Android (Java), I just did that part by doing this.setX(motionEvent.getX())

Since I'm migrating from Native Android to React Native, I'm having a little trouble making this work. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [PanResponder](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/panresponder.html) to get the touch events and then you can use the Animated API to get do the animations to move the view.

See https://moduscreate.com/animated_drag_and_drop_with_react_native/ for a full example.

Comment: I have had tried Responder before but it wasn't working for me for some reason. However, the 'drag and drop' link you referred to me really helped. Thanks a lot!